# Change the Button design in drupal 8

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-8

As i am new to **drupal 8** , i couldn't able to find the CSS code written for the particular grid in drupal 8

Once logged in then click on class Export a gridview will appear.

I needed a slight adjustment to the last row elements which i have highlighted below.

I need to remove the light blue background color and make the font style black.

[image: Class Export Image]

BUt i cannot able to trace the location of the css / html file to make the neccessary changes.

Is it possible to change the button color? or is it a inbuilt functionality where we cannot make any changes?

Any help Appreciated

Comment: You can do a admin sub-theme or a module project to overload the css

Comment: In you custom style-sheet you can override these styles by adding specific class to buttons

Comment: @Awais As i am new to drupal 8 can you give me a eloborated description how to add specific class to buttons in custom style-sheet

Comment: @ShreyasAchar I am also not much aware of Drupal but here are some links that may be help you [LINK1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191644/how-do-i-add-a-css-class-to-a-form-label), [Link2](https://www.drupal.org/project/mayo/issues/2754061)